# Laravel Eloquent WHERE and AND

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have comment table with `id, privacy(0,1,2), comment_body` columns

I am using Larvael `4.2.x` Eloquent to get the result. What I am trying to get is all the comment with the privacy of 0 and 1 from one user.

**What I have tried?**

**Option 1**

```
$user  = User::find(1);

//query will give me comment for privacy = 0
$comment_for_user = $user->comments()->where('privacy','0');
```

**Option 2**

```
//this wont return anything
$comment_for_user = $user->comments()->where('privacy','0')
                                    ->where('privacy',1);
```

**Option 3**

```
//return the result but gets post form all users 
$comment_for_user = $user->comments()->where('privacy','0')
                                    ->Orwhere('privacy',1);
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereIn`.

```
$comment_for_user = $user->comments()->whereIn('privacy', array(0, 1))->get();
```

You can find more useful methods in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent).